# Does TortoiseHg allow the CLI (i.e. "Log Output") to be replaced with, say, Powershell on Windows

Tags: shell, powershell, mercurial, tortoisehg

I use the Log Output window in TortoiseHg to access advanced features of Mercurial from the command line, and it would be nice to use this along with Powershell features, e.g. like, at a minimum, [aliasing the "mq" command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial#Versioning_our_patch_set).

Is it possible to specify the command host used in the Log Output window?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no such possibility in version 2.4 of TortoiseHg. 
If you really need any advanced support just write with suggestions to TortoiseHg [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-discuss).

It seems that in 2.5 Output Log window will get [tons of upgrades](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/changesets/tip/keyword%28%22docklog%22%29) anyway.